# Let X be a nonempty set. Let x∈X. Show that the collection ={U⊆X:U=∅ or x∈U} is a topology for X.

Tags: general-topology, proof-writing

Let $X$ be a nonempty set.  Let $x \in X$. Show that the collection $ \mathfrak T = \{ U \subseteq X : U = \emptyset$ or  $ x \in U \}$ is a topology for X.

I know I need to show that this collection meets all 3 requirements for a topology.

Here is my attempt at a start.

Assume $X$ is a nonempty set.  Let $ x \in X$ .

1. First condition X and $\emptyset$ must be $\in \mathfrak T$. How do I show this?
2. I think I can prove the union is part of the topology.
3. I am not sure how to prove that the finite intersection of elements in $\mathfrak T$ are in $\mathfrak T$.

Comment: You are correct. I fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of $\mathfrak{T}$ tells you explicitly that $\varnothing\in\mathfrak{T}$. To see that $X\in\mathfrak{T}$, just notice that $x\in X$, so $X\in\mathfrak{T}$ by the other part of the definition of $\mathfrak{T}$.

For the third condition, suppose that $U,V\in\mathfrak{T}$. If one (or both) of $U$ and $V$ is empty, then $U\cap V=\varnothing\in\mathfrak{T}$. Otherwise, $x\in U$ and $x\in V$, so $x\in U\cap V$, which by definition means that $U\cap V\in\mathfrak{T}$.

At this point it would be a good idea to see if you can write up the proof of the second condition (closure under unions).

Comment: I think I have a proof for the second one.  I am going to work tonight and see if I can come up the rest!